# Cursor position/index on textarea onClick event in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scenario : User makes onClick on a textarea(somewhere between the content without selecting any character just a click). Using javascript need to find the position of the cursor.
  We had following script :

```
comp.focus();
var range = document.selection.createRange();
range.text='|';
var oldval = comp.value;
var pos= oldval.index('|');
```

Code was running with IE <11. With IE 11 ''dcoument.selection' was undefined. Then document says with IE11 "document.selection" should be "document.getSelection". Hence tried the following :

```
comp.focus();
var range = document.getSelection().createRange();
```

WIth ver11 , "document.getSelection().createRange()" says errors : Object doesnt support the propery or mehtod 'createRange()'.
   Then tried to get object of 'var sel = document.getSelection()'. When i try to print as alert 'sel' , it says 'cannot get property toString on undefiend or null references' 
   1. With older version document.selection.createRange worked well even if there isnt any character seelcted/highlighted. But with IE11 its not as such.
   2. Please let me know how to createRange evne if there isnt any selected characters.
   Need solution/suggestion to proceed.......

Comment: You should use the properties `selectionDirection`, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`. The property `selectionDirection` will have a string saying `'forward'` or `'backward'`. The other 2 define where the selection starts and ends. They will both have the same value if no text is selected. To get the selection, you can use a method like `textarea.value.substr()`.

Comment: My logic , no content selected just a click. insert a placeholder at tat position and find tat placeholder index in the textbox value to get the cursor position. (1)  'selectionstart and end' what values does it result in, meanby in case of no text selected tat value wud be the cursor index value ? (2) So theres no range value can be obtained with non-selected content ?

Comment: It varies. But it works like this: If you have the cursor *anywhere* but *nothing is selected*, you will have the cursor position (e.g.: 6th caracter). Otherwise, the `selectionEnd` will have the value where the cursor currently is (e.g.: 0th char or 150th char). The `selectionStart` is where the selection started. `selectionDirection` will be `'forward'` if the `selectionEnd` is higher than `selectionStart`, `'backward'` otherwise. Sometimes, only specific to `<textarea>`, it *may*  have the value `'none'`, which you can ifnore.

Comment: I know I'm an awful teacher and I suck at explaining. Run `var input=document.getElementById('search').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
alert(['Direction:',input.selectionDirection,'\r\n','Start:',input.selectionStart,'\r\n','End:',input.selectionEnd].join(''));` from your browser (using the console, in the element inspector of your browser). It will only work specifically here and nowhere else. This will show what happens with multiple values. It will use the search box to show the behaviour of the values.

Answer (score -1):

I use this function to get cursor position:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var input = this.get(0);
        if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
        if ('selectionStart' in input) {
            // Standard-compliant browsers
            return input.selectionStart;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            // IE
            input.focus();
            var sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var selLen = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            sel.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
            return sel.text.length - selLen;
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The following code returns cursor position:

```
comp.getCursorPosition();
```

works fine with IE11